# Удаление кнопки с панели с помощью ActionListner

Tags: java

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка по нажатию исчезала?
Предполагаю, что это как-то связано со слушателем, но как конкретно удалить кнопку (или сделать невидимой?) не знаю.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class GraphTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Hello!");                   //JFrame
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        Container container = frame.getContentPane();           //Container
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");              //JButton
        button.addActionListener(new MyActionListner());
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();                            //JPanel
        panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();      //GBC
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;

        panel.add(button, gbc);
        container.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyActionListner implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(1);
        //Вот здесь должна отключаться кнопка
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы динамически удалить компонент с панели `Swing` вам нужно следующим образом определить `listener`:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");              
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

button.addActionListener(e -> {
     System.out.println("remove button");
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            panel.remove(button);
            panel.updateUI();
        });
});
```

Comment: Это, я так понимаю, работает в более поздних версиях? Версия 1.7.0_79 выдаёт эксепшен, мол Лямбда-выражения не поддерживаются на данном уровне языка.

Comment: @dtcobra я использовать лямбды лишь для краткости, никто не запрещает использовать анонимные классы.